# Using CURL to play Youtube videos

Tags: php, json, curl, oembed

I'm using CURL to get Youtube page like this:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyPnQw_Lqds";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

It seems the video doesn't play, I don't know why. I found a script which solves this problem by setting the data as `format json` and then decodes the `json` as plain `html` like this:

```
$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" . $url. "&format=json";

$curl = curl_init($youtube);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($return, true);
echo $result['html'];
```

Im trying to "merge" this two scripts to function as one. I put the scripts together like this:

[PHPFiddle EXAMPLE, CLICK THE RUN(F9) BUTTON](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qnf-twg)

As you can see the video in the top doesn't play. If you scroll down to the bottom you will see another video (which is the video echoed by the JSON) this one can actually be played.

How do I get the upper(top) video to play? I was thinking about first "finding" the "object" and then format as json etc. But Im afraid this will mess up the page.

Comment: For me, both the videos play. I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: @AgilE That's weird...Do they play in the PHPfiddle? It doesn't play for me at home with all browsers and windows 8, and also not at work with windows 7...

Comment: I tried it locally and it works. But the video takes a long time to show up. It's a black box initially, but then loads up.